# Как правильно обработать JSON средствами PHP?

Tags: php, json

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь обработать JSON:

```
{
"status":"error",
"code":400,
"error":[
     "params": [
        {
            "name":"lead_time",
            "message":"\"lead_time\" cannot be blank."
        },
        {
            "name":"lead_id",
            "message":"\"lead_id\" cannot be blank."
        },
     ],
     "type":"invalid_param_error",
     "message":"Invalid data parameters"
]
```

}

Делаю так:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
$status = $response['status']; // Получаем переменную
```

Этот код работает, если я вытаскиваю первые две строчки status и code. Как вытащить данные, которые находятся внутри "error" и "params"?

Comment: `$response['error']['params']` `$response['error']['params'][0]['message']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Обработать JSON

json уже обработан, с помощью json_decode.

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

В `$response` обычный php-массив и работать с ним нужно, как с обычным массивом.

```
$errorParams = $response['error']['params'];
foreach ($errorParams as $param) {
  echo "{$param['name']}: {$param['message']}<br/>\n";
}
```